# JQuery templating

Tags: jquery

Is it possible in a JQuery template to specify an particular image depending upon the value in the field (in this case it is a boolean field {MainYN} and I want to show a tick image if the value is true and a cross image if the value is false)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunatly JQuery template makes a simple replace of {Variable} with the values inserted in the ArrayValue passed to the template function.
I've solved this problem passing the full path of the image to the template.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways this can be accomplished but the general steps are the same.

In your template, just add some if logic:

```
{{if MainYN === true}}
  <img src="tick.png" />
{{else}}
  <img src="cross.png" />
{{/if}}
```